# Can I use AWS CloudFormation with a custom AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, snapshot, amazon-ami, aws-cloudformation

I want to use an AMI that have not been created from a snapshot. The AMI was created using a virtual machine and then I used CLI tools to create the instance and the AMI.

This instance have installed cloud-init. Could I use this AMI to create instances using cloudformation?
Do I need to install more software to use that service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely, that is a very common use case:

> Amazon Web Services (AWS) publishes many Amazon Machine Images (AMIs)
>   that contain common software configurations for public use. In
>   addition, the AWS developer community has published many custom AMIs.
>   You can also create your own custom AMIs so that you can quickly and
>   easily start new instances that have everything you need for your
>   application. For example, if your application is a website or a web
>   service, your AMI could include a web server, the associated static
>   content, and the code for the dynamic pages. After you launch an
>   instance with this AMI, your application is running and ready to
>   accept requests.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/BoostrappingApplicationsWithAWSCloudFormation.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Should you plan to use Cloudformation:Init inside your template to add additional configuration when your instance will start, be sure to install cfn tools as well (cfn-init, cfn-hup, cfn-signal...)

More details about Cloudformation:Init : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html

How to install cfn helper scripts : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-helper-scripts-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

When you are specifying the instance in the cloud formation script you can use "ImageID": ""  <- put in the AMI ID

ImageId

```
Provides the unique ID of the Amazon Machine Image (AMI) that was assigned during registration.

Required: Yes

Type: String

Update requires: Replacement
```